# importing classes global name not defined

Tags: python

sample1.py

```
class1:
    
    def function(self): 
    
        dbcursor.execute('UPDATE Table')
```

main.py

```
from sample1 import class1

inventoryDb = inventory.connect('sample.db')

dbcursor = inventoryDb.cursor()

class = class1()

class.function()
```

> > NameError: global name 'dbcursor' is not defined

## What is causing error here? And, how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbcursor` is only defined in main.py.  Why don't you pass it as a parameter to your function in sample1.py?  Something like

```
def function(self, dbcursor):
    dbcursor.execute('UPDATE Table')

class_ = class1()
inventoryDb = inventory.connect('sample.db')
class_.function(inventoryDb.cursor())
```